# get total and free memory in c++

Tags: c++, memory

Does C++ have method like in java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

I am using in this way

```
long mem0 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
/*
stuff to do
*/ 
long mem1 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();              
System.out.println(mem1-mem0);
```

to find memory used by program. Is here any analogues in C++?

Comment: why do you need to know? Would using a simple memory profiler do the job or do you have some kind of runtime decisions to make based on that information?

Comment: there are some efficient memory managment tools for C++, like Valgring (Linux only).

Comment: also, this is pretty much covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122277/getting-memory-information-with-qt

Comment: "Does C++ have method like in java" - BTW, Java do **not** have this methods. They are part of standard Java's library. Unfortunally C++ hasn't functionality you need in it's standard library

Comment: @borisbn to nitpick, there's no "standard library". there is just a standard, and a couple of more or less standards compliant library implementations each with their couple of additions ;)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin - isn't the STL a standard (template) library? Also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library

Comment: @ddriver the term "standard library" is common, yes. but it does not refer to **the** standard library, but to a specific implementation of the standard. also, c++ "standard" library and stl are two different things :)

Comment: @ddriver for example, the glibc (one of the c libraries available for a couple of platforms) **does** include nonstandard extensions that allow extraction of memory stats. I was just objecting to "C++ hasn't functionality you need in it's standard library" because that is true for the standard, but not for the libraries. A slight difference, but, I think, a relevant one.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin - there might be a lot of implementations, but there is a reason it is called a STANDARD library - it is a standard, even if the implementations are different they need to conform to the standard. And the STL is part of that standard library.

Comment: @ddriver generally that's true. But, as I said, different implementations of the standard come with different nonstandard extensions, that are, nonetheless, part of the library. And what makes you think the stl is part of the standard library? afaik, and wikipedia shares this opinion, "The C++ Standard Library is based upon conventions introduced by the Standard Template Library (STL). Although the C++ Standard Library and the STL share many features, neither is a strict superset of the other."

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin part of the library but not part of the standard library. On the rest you are correct, the SL and the STL are different entities.

Comment: @ddriver allright then. Let's agree to disagree :) Have a one-up!

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin. I have some stuff to do with the memory obtained in ruttime

Answer (score 2):

Its not specified in the C++ standard, under Windows you need to use the WinAPI [For example this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and under linux you need to use a library or call syscalls.

Comment: I am interested in Linux version, could you give me a link to libraries and syscalls?