# How to get the RAM memory size programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I am looking for a way to retrieve the RAM memory size of my computer in C++ with Qt.

My primary target is Windows, if that would make things easier.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122277/getting-memory-information-with-qt), you'll have to use something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx) or the one mentioned there, depending on your needs.

Comment: "Programatically"... It might also be problematic but that's a different story :)

Comment: Thank you @ghostofstandardspast.
I tried this code:
MEMORYSTATUSEX memory_status;
    QString size;
    ZeroMemory(&memory_status, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
    memory_status.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
    if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memory_status)) {
     size =memory_status.ullTotalPhys / (1024 * 1024);
    }

But I got this:"\231" in the size... do you know why?

Comment: @chani, [You can't just assign an integer to a `QString` and expect the integer to be converted to a string](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#operator-eq-6).

Comment: OK. so now I got 3993 (if i divided it by 1024 - I got 3.8994... and after convert it to int: I got 3.). But my memory is 4 GB...

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, I tried the code that in the link you gave, but is gave to me the same answer as before (3.8994... MB). do you think that I have to round the number up?
In c# code (when using the Win32_PhysicalMemory class) I got the correct number-4. any idea?

Comment: For various reasons, Windows is sometimes not able to use 100% of your physical RAM. There are several ways you can handle this: (1) Just accept it, and display the slightly-less-than-4GB value. (2) Round up to the nearest GB. (3) Query the actual RAM sticks installed and add up their capacity (e.g. using DMI queries). This may be a privileged operation unavailable to processes not running as an administrator.

Comment: I did it. Thanks to all of you!!