# Qt5 Memory Polling

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, qt5

I'm new here so I apologize if I have posted in the wrong area or am missing some information in my question. **Is it possible to poll global memory usage in windows with Qt5?** I've searched through the [Qt5 Classes](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/classes.html) and I didn't find anything that I thought would fit the bill. For more specificity, I'm looking for something similar to [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Seems unlikely, but the version of the Qt documentation you linked to is very old.

Comment: There is nothing like this in Qt5; see older question [Getting memory information with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122277/getting-memory-information-with-qt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt doesn't offer a portable API to do so, since querying the OS for memory usage is indeed, an **OS specific** task.

You can however, write a **wrapper** class, which uses the correct API depending on the OS you are running.

As an example, on Windows you could use the API you have already mentioned (**GlobalMemoryStatusEx**), while on Linux you could use the [sysinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) API).

Once you have identified the APIs to use for the target platforms, you can use **conditional compilation** to compile only the correct code for each platform, while offering the same interface to the outside world.

Qt offers a few defines (**Q_OS_**) which are set or not depending on the target OS. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_WIN) for more details.

Example:

```
/*!
 * \brief MemoryUsage::getMemoryUsage
 * \return the overall memory usage in percent.
 */
int MemoryUsage::getMemoryUsage()
{
    int result = 0;

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    struct sysinfo sys_info;

    sysinfo(&sys_info);

    unsigned long long total = sys_info.totalram *(unsigned long long)sys_info.mem_unit / 1024;
    unsigned long long free = sys_info.freeram *(unsigned long long)sys_info.mem_unit/ 1024;

    result = (total - free) * 100 / total;
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);

    GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);

    result = statex.dwMemoryLoad);
#endif

    return result;
}
```

With the same trick you must also ensure the correct headers are included (e.g. don't include  when you are compiling for Linux).

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the response!